What is the Chinese name for ´ (acute accent) and ` (grave accent)?
This is the Wikidata [1] item for ´ (acute accent). The title of the linked article in Chinese Wikipedia (zh-cn) is "尖音符".
This is the Wikidata [1] item for ` (grave accent). The title of the linked article in Chinese Wikipedia (zh-cn) is "重音符".
The following quote was retrieved from page 116 in the book "现代西班牙语 4"


2．指示代词都不再使用重音符号。例如：Estos zapatos son más caros que aquellos。当然，如果可能产生歧义，仍然需要添加重音符合加以区分。例如：在 ¿Por qué compraron aquéllos libros usados? 中，aquéllos 是主语，代指购书者，而在 ¿Por qué compraron aquellos libros usados? 中，aquellos 是形容词，修饰中心词 libros。为区分二者，前者需要使用重音符号。).

Translation in English:


Accent marks are no longer used for demonstrative pronouns. For example: "Estos zapatos son más caros que aquellos". Of course, if ambiguity may arise, accent marks still need to be added to distinguish them. For example: in "¿Por qué compraron aquéllos libros usados?", "aquéllos" is the subject, which refers to the book buyer, while in ¿Por qué compraron aquellos libros usados?, "aquellos" is an adjective that modifies the central word "libros". To distinguish the two, the former requires the use of accent marks.).


As we can see in the quote, "重音符号" is used to refer to the accent used in Spanish (acute accent). However, in Chinese Wikipedia, the name for acute accent is "尖音符". My main question is: What is the name used for ` (grave accent) and ´ (acute accent) in Mainland China?
I think people from China that are studying the French language can answer this question because French uses both acute and grave accents and reliable books for learning French aimed to Chinese students might refer to these characters using their Chinese names. My secondary question is: How do French books aimed to Chinese native speakers refer to the acute accent and the grave accent?
[1] For those that are not very familiar with Wikidata: Wikidata a the sister project of Wikipedia. One of its uses is to centralize the links to all Wikipedia language editions.

Very unfortunately, the Chinese terms aren't very clear to those not in the field.
The terms are as follows:

Accent mark: 重音符號 (literally symbols for marking stress/accents)

Grave accent: 重音符 (no 號; literally the stressed/accentuated sound symbol)
Acute accent: 尖音符、銳音符 (again, no 號; literally the sharp/acute sound symbol)



Your translation is correct; the usage of 重音符號 is also correct, as it doesn't mean grave accent, but just a generic accent mark. Modern Spanish doesn't use grave accents, so the only thing that accent marks can refer to in this context is the acute accent.

重音 accent, stress
音符 note, musical note, semantic complement
尖锐 sharp, sharpness, acute, shrill, sharp-pointed, incisive, penetrating, keen
符号 symbol, mark, sign
抑 restrain, restrict, keep down
accent grave: 开音符,  抑音符号
accent acute: 锐音符, 尖音符, 尖锐重音, 闭音符
La tilde (el acento) no se usa en esta palabra (aquéllos) hace mucho tiempo.
The tilde (accent) has not been in use in this word (aquéllos) for a very long time.
这个单词（aquéllos）的抑音符号已经被去掉很久了.
La frase sería:
That should be:
应该写:
¿Por qué compraron ellos libros usados?
他们为什么正在买旧书?
Why did they buy old books?
Por qué compraron aquellos libros usados?
他们为什么正在买那些旧书?
Why did they buy those old books?
